# Swagger UI/Swashbuckle response description with caret not rendering correctly

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am using Swashbuckle with Swagger UI in a .Net project. I am using the following attribute on a controller.

```
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "IEnumerable<EmployeeModel>", typeof(IEnumerable<EmployeeModel>))]
```

The generated JSON doc produces this:

```
"responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "IEnumerable<EmployeeModel>",
            "schema": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/ResourceModels.EmployeeModel"
              }
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "BadRequest"
          }
        }
```

Swagger UI however only displays IEnumerable and drops the `<EmployeeModel>`. I am sure the carets are the culprit. Is there a workaround for this?

[image]

Comment: It would be better to remove this description altogether because the response isn't an `IEnumerable<EmployeeModel>` but an array of `EmployeeModel` as the schema already describes.

Comment: IEnumerable is a collection, not an array. Although the JSON type returned is an array (as described in the documentation), the endpoint returns a collection.

Comment: I know that, but for your consumers, which might not 'talk' .NET, it's just an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Swagger:

That's actually a bug in the description. That field is gfm, meaning anything in <> will be treated as html, so if you want those characters to appear you need to escape them.